# Databricks Autoloader throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: databricks, databricks-autoloader

I'm trying the simplest auto loader example included in the databricks website

https://databricks.com/notebooks/Databricks-Data-Integration-Demo.html

```
df = (spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
      .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
      .load(input_data_path))
 
(df.writeStream.format("delta")
 .option("checkpointLocation", chkpt_path)
   .table("iot_stream"))
```

I keep getting this message:

> IllegalArgumentException: cloudFiles.schemaLocation Could not find required option: schemaLocation. Please provide a schema location using `cloudFiles.schemaLocation` for storing inferred schema and supporting schema evolution.

If providing cloudFiles.schemaLocation is required, why do the examples everywhere are missing it? what's the underlying issue here?

Comment: Did you got the answer to this issue as I am also facing the same error and even after trying other options, I am not able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what is going on is that you are not explicitly setting the `.option("cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode")`

Which means it is being set to the default which is "addNewColumns" as per https://docs.databricks.com/ingestion/auto-loader/options.html

And that requires you set the .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", path) in the reader.

Thus you are inadvertently requiring it and not setting it.

Answer (score 0):

In the example notebook there is this config here being set on session:

```
spark.sql("SET spark.databricks.cloudFiles.schemaInference.enabled=true")
```

Consider you are running the same autoloader read/write code block, are you receiving the error message even enabling this schema inference setting?